# What is the actual birthplace of Sita ji according to scriptures?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, temple, sita, geography

Recently Prime Minister of India Narendra Modi [was in Nepal at the Janaki Temple](https://thewire.in/diplomacy/pm-modi-announces-rs-100-crore-package-to-develop-janakpur-in-nepal) in Janakpur which is supposed to be the birthplace of Goddess Sita and I came to know about this place due to the news coverage his visit got. But there is also a place in India known as Sitamarhi where Sita ji is believed to have been born according to local belief.

I know there are many such places related to Ramayan that have more than one contenders but **does the Ramayan or any other scripture tells us clearly about the birthplace of Goddess Sita?**

Comment: Related Q: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22475/did-lord-ramas-wife-devi-sita-belong-to-nepal-in-which-place-did-she-stay-duri

Comment: Sitaji surfaced from the surface of the earth when Janaka was ploughing some (ritual) field in Mithila region...Both Janakpur and Sitamarhi were part of Mithila region...I believe the field was in Sitamarhi but she was brought up in Janakapur...

Comment: It has not been mentioned properly anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Sita was likely born somewhere in jungles of Himalayas, perhaps close to Kailash mountain.

The story of Birth of Sita starts with that of Vedvati. When Ravan received strong boons from Shiva, he went around the earth fighting many Kings and destroying many kingdoms. Once he was roaming around in jungles of Himalayas, that's when he spotted beautiful Vedvati.

> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

When Ravan insulted Vedvati, she decided to do agni samadhi. She deliberately didn't curse Ravan, instead wished to be born as Ayonija Kanya, or young girl  born without a womb.

> [image]
> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

Vedvati indeed takes rebirth as a young girl like she wished for, lying inside a lotus. **Thus, Sita was born. This place is likely somewhere in Himalayas.**

> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

The story does not end here though. Ravan took the girl to Lanka anyways. However, his mantri identified the girl as cause of Ravan's death, hence advised him to get rid of her.

> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

Out of fear, Ravan threw the girl in Sea. Earth took her in her care. She reappeared again in the middle of Yagya bhumi of Raja Janak, where he was performing Yagya. (I believe this is the point of interest today).

> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

**Thus, Sita was reborn again.** In fact, she is called Sita because she came out of line drawn by a plow. Unfortunately, nothing much is mentioned about the place of Yagya.

> [image]
> Sarga 17, Uttar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan

A less detailed but very similar story of How Raja Janak found Sita is told to Shri Ram in [Sarga 66, Bal Kand, Valmiki Ramayan](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=66). Please see Shlokas 13 onwards.